# RER - Can't view logs, doesn't seem to fire

Tags: remote-event-receiver

I've made a Remote Event Receiver, making it trigger on `ItemAdded`, `ItemUpdated` and `ItemCheckedIn`.

the app is hosted on an internal server (not Azure), and building and deploying it works. I can thrust the app etc.

But, the RER doesn't seem to fire at all. Furtheron: if I click "view logs", I get the "something went wrong" page.

[image: View logs: Something went wrong.]

Element.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="101">
    <Receiver>
      <Name>SPRERItemAdded</Name>
      <Type>ItemAdded</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/SPRER.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>SPRERItemUpdated</Name>
      <Type>ItemUpdated</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/SPRER.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
    <Receiver>
      <Name>SPRERItemCheckedIn</Name>
      <Type>ItemCheckedIn</Type>
      <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      <Url>~remoteAppUrl/Services/SPRER.svc</Url>
    </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Snippet of test code, to see if it triggers at least:

```
public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
    {
         if (clientContext != null)
         {
              clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
              clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         }

         //Get current Item
         List curList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListId);
         ListItem curItem = curList.GetItemById(properties.ItemEventProperties.ListItemId);

         clientContext.Load(curItem);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

         curItem["PGQCDomain"] = "test";
         curItem["name"] = "anotherTest";
         curItem.Update();
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         return;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the RER trigger, and why can't I see the logs to debug this problem?